# How req.secure checks that incoming request is for secure server or not in https secure communication?

Tags: node.js, security, express, https

```
app.all('*', function(req, res, next){
    console.log('req start: ',req.secure, req.hostname, req.url, app.get('port'));
  if (req.secure) {
    return next();
  };

 res.redirect('https://'+req.hostname+':'+app.get('secPort')+req.url);
});
```

req.secure was set on the incoming request message. So req.secure will be set to   true.In that case the incoming request has come to secure server. So, the rest of the processing can go forward as usual.If incoming request is for insecure  server, that is local host colon 3000, then I'm going to use this function  called res.redirect that is available in express. So I am setting up this  request as saying `HTTPS//`.So I want know how redirected all http request to  https?How req.secure checks that the request is for secure server or for  insecure server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`req.secure` checks if the protocol is HTTPS and it's the same as:

```
req.protocol === 'https'
```

See the docs for more info:

- https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#req.secure

To force all traffic to be redirected to https you can do something like this:

```
server.use('/path', function(req, res, next) {  
  if(!req.secure) {
    var secureUrl = "https://" + req.headers['host'] + req.url; 
    res.writeHead(301, { "Location":  secureUrl });
    res.end();
  }
  next();
});
```

as explained in this article:

- https://www.themarketingtechnologist.co/force-express-to-handle-requests-over-https/